# Copy row by row from sheet1 to sheet2 with empty rows between

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy rows from sheet1 (number of rows can vary up to 700) to sheet2.

Sheet1 column A is text, B, C and D have formulas.

On sheet2 each row should have five empty rows in between. The paste should start at row 17 (next 22, etc.).

I checked Google but did not know how to amend the code I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, not sure if this is what you want. Column A are String only, column B to D contain Formula. You mentioned to leave five empty rows in between but I saw your description also mentioned to start at row 17 then the next should start at row 22, which is four empty rows. You can change the number of empty rows by changing the offset from 4 to 5.

[image]

[image]

```
Sub copy_to_sheet2()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim count_1 As Integer
Dim count_2 As Integer
Dim offset As Integer
Dim last_row As Long

'your workbook / sheets name
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

'get total rows of sheet 1
last_row = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
count_1 = 1 'sheet 1 counter
count_2 = 17 'sheet 2 counter
offset = 0 'offset / empty rows default value

    'loop sheet 1 from 1st row to last row
    For i = 1 To last_row

        If i = 2 Then
            offset = 4 '2nd loop change offset to 4
        ElseIf i > 2 Then
            offset = offset + 4 'subsequent loop offset + 4
        End If

        'copy sheet 1 column A to D row by row & paste values to sheet 2 with offset row by row
        ws1.Range("A" & count_1 & ":" & "D" & count_1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        ws2.Range("A" & count_2 + offset).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        'add counter
        count_1 = count_1 + 1
        count_2 = count_2 + 1

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: hey Anthony. thank you very much. exactly what i needed. i am reading up on vba so i don’t have to ask these basic questions. thank you again for your help!

Comment: @Mr.B Hey, glad I was able to help, could you kindly click on the accept button since the problem is solved :D